# How to match two data frame with constraints in R?

Tags: r, database, datatable, matching

I have two kinds of data set.

One is the data that people have on the elevator and the other is that the elevator arrived on the first floor.

this is the data of people who used the elevator

```
usercode    board time(sec) 
1           165 
2           167 
3           170 
4           340 
5           351 
6           820 
7           830 
8           1200    
9           1201    
10          1400
```

and this is the data of elevator schedule

```
elevator code   arrival time
1               164
2               338
3               813
4               1175
5               1367
```

what i want to is

```
usercode    board time(sec) elevator code     elevator arrival time
1           165                 1                   164
2           167                 1                   164
3           170                 1                   164
4           340                 2                   338
5           351                 2                   338
6           820                 3                   813
7           830                 3                   813
8           1200                4                   1175
9           1201                4                   1175
10          1400                5                   1367
```

Help me!! please

Comment: what is the logic behind your match?

Comment: The sentence was not very persuasive so I deleted the sentence !!

Comment: again, what is the logic behind this matching?
on what conditions you match elevator(consider 1) code to user code (consider 1,2,3) or arrival time ( 165,167,170) and so on?

Comment: Since the elevator 1 arrived at 164 seconds, and the "user 1" boarded at 165, the elevator that user 1 boarded is the elevator 1. So, I want to match the elevator code with the minimum difference between user arrival time and elevator arrival time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using the rolling joins in `data.table` as follows:

```
arrival[people, on="arrivaltime_sec", roll=Inf]

#     elevatorcode arrivaltime arrivaltime_sec usercode
#  1:            1         164             165        1
#  2:            1         164             167        2
#  3:            1         164             170        3
#  4:            2         338             340        4
#  5:            2         338             351        5
#  6:            3         813             820        6
#  7:            3         813             830        7
#  8:            4        1175            1200        8
#  9:            4        1175            1201        9
# 10:            5        1367            1400       10
```

data:

```
library(data.table)

people <- fread("usercode,arrivaltime_sec
1,165
2,167
3,170
4,340
5,351
6,820
7,830
8,1200
9,1201
10,1400")

arrival <- fread("elevatorcode,arrivaltime
1,164
2,338
3,813
4,1175
5,1367")

arrival[, arrivaltime_sec := arrivaltime]
```

Answer (score 3):

taking the first data as `dat1` and the second one as `dat2` we can do :

```
  transform(dat1,add=dat2[rowSums(outer(dat1[,2],dat2[,2],">")),],row.names=NULL)

   usercode arrival_time.sec. add.elevator_code add.arrival_time
1         1               165                 1              164
2         2               167                 1              164
3         3               170                 1              164
4         4               340                 2              338
5         5               351                 2              338
6         6               820                 3              813
7         7               830                 3              813
8         8              1200                 4             1175
9         9              1201                 4             1175
10       10              1400                 5             1367
```

Comment: I really appreciated to your answer, however there are some error messages as follows,                                                                                                  
Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : comparison of these types is not implemented

Comment: ensure `dat1[,2]` and `dat2[,2]` are vectors and also numeric/integers. This only works with data.frames.

Comment: u are the best programmer ever. thanks.           however, how can set the constraints like ">30"??!

Comment: What do you mean by `>30`?

Comment: I want to have a constraint of +30. If I apply the +30 constraint to user1, it will match the elevator after 185 seconds such as elevator2.

Comment: Am sorry but I could not understand what you mean by that.